# At What Depth Does The Search of An Object Literal Become Slower Than O(1)?

Tags: javascript, performance, big-o

Code:

```
var PhoneNumbers = {
    "J Smith": 7125551212,
    "A Johnson": 4023331212
}

alert(PhoneNumbers["J Smith"]); // 7125551212
```

The speed of this lookup is O(1). At What depth does the speed become slower than O(1)?

For example:

```
var PhoneNumbers = {
    "J Smith": {
         age: 40,
         phoneNumber: 7125551212
    },
    "A Johnson": {
         age: 40,
         phoneNumber: 7125551212
    }
}

alert(PhoneNumbers["J Smith"]["phoneNumber"]); // 7125551212
```

Does the second example have a speed slower than O(1)?

Comment: by "below" do you mean "slower than"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of nested dictionary lookups is O(N), where N is the depth of the nesting.

The complexity of any **specific** lookup operation (fixed object, fixed keys) is constant (i.e. O(1)): it will always take the same amount of time.

An individual lookup should be in O(1), at least in the "typical" case. Dictionaries are typically implemented as hash tables, which, in theory, could degrade to O(N) (with N being the number of keys in the dictionary), if all keys have the same hash value.

Comment: Just so we're clear, you're talking about the depth of the nesting (in the first example, that's 1) as opposed to the size of the input (in the first example, that's 2), correct?

Comment: You might want to add, that it is still of constant complexity (O(1)) with respect to the size of the data set, which is usually denoted by N.

Comment: @LeviHackwith: Correct; the size of the objects should not matter if the dictionary is nearly collision-free (which it should be).

Comment: @Martinv.Löwis, so what you're saying is if all "keys" are unique, the speed will always be (O(1)) no matter if the object literal has 1 property or ten-thousand?

Comment: @LeviHackwith: In all practical cases, on a industry-proof JS implementation, property lookup should be O(1), yes. In principle, it should be possible to create counter-examples with strings that have colliding hash values. However, these would be unlikely to occur in a real world case (except when created by a malicious JS author).